# View not sending ViewModel to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to send a ViewModel with a `IList<Hole>` from the view to the controller after data is gathered in a for `loop` to pass into a method, however, the ViewModel being passed continues to be null.  What am I missing that is not passing the ViewModel from the View to the Controller?

My ViewModel is:

```
public class HoleViewModel : IEnumerable
    {
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        //public Hole Hole { get; set; }

        public IList<Hole> Holes { get; set; }


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

My View is:

```
@using GT_App.Models
@model GT_App.ViewModel.HoleViewModel

....

<form method="post" action="/Hole/Create">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            @{
                var holeCount = 4;
            }
            <table style="display: inline">
                <thead>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Yardage</th>
                    <th>Par</th>
                    <th>Hdcp</th>
                </thead>
                @for (int i = 0; i < holeCount; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Holes[i].Number)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Holes[i].Yardage)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Holes[i].Par)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Holes[i].Handicap)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

My Controller is:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.FacilityId = new SelectList(db.Facilities, "FacilityId", "Name");
            ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(HoleViewModel holes)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < holes.Holes.Count; i++)
                {

                    var item = new Hole();
                    if (Session["FacilityId"] != null || Convert.ToInt32(Session["FacilityId"]) != 0)
                    {
                        item.FacilityId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["FacilityId"]);
                    }
                    if (Session["CourseId"] != null || Convert.ToInt32(Session["CourseId"]) != 0)
                    {
                        item.CourseId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CourseId"]);
                    }
                    item.Number = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Number" + i]);
                    item.Yardage = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Yardage" + i]);
                    item.Par = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Par" + i]);
                    item.Handicap = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Handicap" + i]);
                    holes.Holes.Add(item);

                }

                // itterate thru collection to add individual holes to Entity
                foreach (Hole hole in holes)
                {
                    db.Holes.Add(hole);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name", Session["CourseId"]);
            //return View(Session["CourseId"]);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Your first Create action does not pass a model to the view, and so the view will have a null model. That's OK, that's normal. Is it when the form is submitted that you have a problem?

Comment: Yes the error is on the "Create" button click.  The error, more specifically, occurs on the "For" loop.  Since the ViewModel is not being passed in, the for loop does not recognize holes.Holes.Count().

Answer (score 0):

If there's a model validation error in your second `Create` action, then typically you'd return the view again using the submitted model, which would then show the validation errors on the webpage.

You're not doing that - you're redirecting to the `Index` action regardless of whether the model was valid. I'd put the `RedirectToAction` call just after the call to `SaveChanges`, and then at the end of the method `return View(holes);`.

Oh, and I wouldn't put the `SaveChanges` call inside the loop. Do it after the loop. There are other issues with that code, but I'm going to stop there... :-)

Comment: I am not able to get passed the beginning of the for loop. Since the ViewModel is not being passed in, the for loop does not recognize holes.Holes.Count().